# Data Migration from one SharePoint site to site in a different domain including AD user data

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, active-directory, azure

I have managed to migrate an existing sharepoint site lists to the Azure except for the 1 list in which the people picker columns are appearing blank.

Our existing app  is in ‘domain1' and we have a different domain in azure i.e. ‘domain2’ so although the Active Directory(AD) users are the same, domains differ.

I need a solution which will migrate the whole list including the columns which are of type Person and Group

We had created same users from 'Domain1' in 'Domain2' through AD in the Domain controller. But these users got saved with different tp_ID in the 'UserInfo' table in the wss content database.
And now the tp_ID are not matching of accounts with same user so it's not showing us correct data for columns having people picker type.

Is it possible by using powershell script?

Comment: Not sure how to do it on the SP-online but on premise you would use Move-SPUser cmdlet. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607729.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In the SharePoint Online migration process, you need to save the source site as a template and attach it to the destination site.

After that, you can copy the SharePoint site content to the destination to complete the SharePoint Online migration process.

The general steps are:

1. Save the source site as a template
2. Then attach the saved template to the destination site in SharePoint Online
3. Copy the content from source site to the destination site in SharePoint Online

Get more here: http://expert-advice.org/2017/01/migrate-sharepoint-online-different-sharepoint-onlineoffice-365-tenants/

Comment: We had created same users from 'Domain1' in 'Domain2' through AD in the Domain controller. But these users got saved with different tp_ID in the 'UserInfo' table in the wss content database.
And now the tp_ID are not matching of accounts with same user so it's not showing us correct data for columns having people picker type.

Is it possible by using powershell script?

Comment: If we follow all the steps as you said, data which belongs to people picker type do not get migrated . It shows blank/null .